# Java Generic type : difference between List <? extends Number> and List <T extends Number>

Tags: java

Java Generic type : what is the difference between

```
(1) List <? extends Number>   
(2) List <T extends Number>
```

as per my understanding

(1) `List <? extends Number>`  is the 
Readonly List of "unknown" data type with super class "Number". we can read the element only but can not add

(2) `List <T extends Number>`
List of data type with super class "Number". we can **read and add** the elements into the list

Please see the below code example

```
class TestGen{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double result = 0.0;

        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        intList.add(10);
        intList.add(20);
        intList.add(30);

        result = TestGen.sumOfList1(intList);
        System.out.println("Result=" + result);
        result = TestGen.sumOfList2(intList);
        System.out.println("Result=" + result);
    }

    public static double sumOfList1(List<? extends Number> list) {
        double s = 0.0;
        for (Number n : list)
            s += n.doubleValue();
        return s;
    }

    public static <T extends Number> double sumOfList2(List<T> list) {
        double s = 0.0;

        // getting error while trying to add new element 
        // list<T> is not applicable for argument(Integer) : Why ?
        list.add(new Integer(40));

        for (Number n : list)
            s += n.doubleValue();

        return s;
    }
}
```

When I am trying to add the Integer (or even Number object) into the sumOfList2 then getting the error. Please explain what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Basic difference is if you use `T extends Number` then you can refer to the type `T`:
`list.add((T) new Integer(40));`

Where as if you use `? extends Number` then you can *not* refer to the type, but you can still say:
`((List<Integer>)list).add((int) s);`

Comment: Not sure who down voted....this solution works,  can you please shed a light why casting is required.
       list.add((T) new Integer(40));    
while we are adding the object of sub class only (Integer is subclass of Number)

Comment: I'm guessing it gives you the `type safety` warning, when you cast it to `T`.

Comment: I guess, as per the type of argument, List can accept values of type T, and hence you need to cast the argument to add() to T

Answer (score 13):

In isolation, there isn't much difference.  However, two instances of `List<? extends Number>` in a single context are completely unrelated, while two instances of `List<T extends Number>` in a single context refer to the same `T` and the same interface.

```
public void addAll(List<? extends Number> to, List<? extends Number> from) {
    for (Number n: from) {
        to.add(n);
    }
}
```

This method fails because `n` can't be added to `to`, and also failed because the member types  of `from` and `to` can be completely different.

```
public <T> void addAll(List<T extends Number> to, List<T extends Number> from) {
    for (T n: from) {
        to.add(n);
    }
}
```

This method compiles fine.  It isn't necessary; `Collections` has a better version, but it will run without error.

Comment: In fact `addAll(List<T extends Number> to, ...` doesn't even compile.  It needs to be `<T extends Number> void addAll(List<T> to, ...`

Answer (score 1):

In `sumOfList2`, `T` is a specific subclass of `Number`, but it can be any of them. For example `T` could be `BigDecimal`, and you can't add an `Integer` to a `List<BigDecimal>`.

If you want to be able to add any types of number to the list, it has to be a `List<Number>`:

```
public static double sumOfList2(List<Number> list) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first case is very simple and its known from `T extends Number` That T is an Object which is of type Number class or its child.
This means if we have a method that uses T as a type of Number we can manipulate our method accordingly i.e

```
<T extends Number> void myMethod ( List <T> num){
     num.add(1); // 1 is an Integer
     num.add(2.3) // 2.3 is a Double
}
```

But in this *Wild character '?' * case we don't know what kind of Object is going to be referenced even though if it extends Number, but it can be any kind of Object

```
void myMethod( List <? extends Number> num){
     // num.add(1); // not a valid statement, as we dont know if '1' is of the type '?'
     // num.add(2.3)  // not a valid statement, as we dont know if '2.3' is of the type '?'
}
```

So the only value that can be written down in such statements is **null**, as any type of Object can be null.

```
    void myMethod( List <? extends Number> num){
      num.add(null)
    }
```

Such methods are Read Only methods.

Comment: your first sample can not be compiled actually.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
List <? extends Number>
```

It would be appropriate to use

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4);
```

Which does not throw you an error.

```
List <Double> list = Arrays.asList(0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4);
```

then you can add it to

```
result = TestGen.sumOfList1(list);
```

2) List

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(0);
list.add(1); Would do the job.
```