# Why is it necessary to specify generic parameters after they have already been specified?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following interface

```
public interface Foo<T extends Bar> {

    T getBar();
}
```

And the following class

```
public class FooFinder {

    public Foo<? extends Bar> getFoo(final String fooName) {
        return knownFoos.get(fooName);
    }

    private Map<String, Foo<? extends Bar>> knownFoos = new HashMap<>();
}
```

My question is this. Why is it required that I specify that `getFoo` returns a `Foo<T extends Bar>` and the values of `knownFoos` are `Foo<T Extends Bar>` when `Foo` can only ever be a `Foo<T extends Bar>` because of it's signature? I may naively believe that it has something to do with type erasure, but I'm not sure.

**Addendum:**

Take the `Foo` interface. `T` can only ever be a `Bar` or a subclass of `Bar`. The code and compiler make this clear. If we were to attempt the following

```
Foo<T extends Object> fooObj = new Foo<String>();
```

The compiler would tell you that String is not in the bound `<T extends Bar>`. So at compile time, we know that there is no `Foo` that can ever exist that is not bounded as `T extends Bar`. This is different from the `List<T>` example as there is no bound to `T` other than that it extends `Object` unless you specify otherwise.

With this in mind, if the compiler is intelligent enough to know the bounds of `Foo` can only be `<T extends Bar>`, why is it still required that I set the bound explicitly?

Comment: What would you rather specify?

Comment: Where does `T` come from in `public Foo<T extends Bar> getFoo`? I don't see any type parameter `T` defined for the class or the method.

Comment: @Zymus Also, `T getBar();` won't compile unless you make it `abstract`. At this point, I would ask you to stop and post a valid example.

Comment: I mistakenly made the first code block a `class` instead of the intended `interface`. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to as long as you don't mind using a different language.

Other languages make more use of a feature called type inference which does what you expect: look at the code and figure out stuff on its on. This of course comes at some cost. For example Scala is known for long compile times and sometimes confusing situations, when type inference doesn't inference the types the developer things it should.

With Java almost everything has to be specified manually (although there is now some type inference with the <> operator.

The alternatives you mentioned

```
Foo

Foo<T extends Bar>

Foo<? extends Bar>
```

[are in fact different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187005/java-generic-type-difference-between-list-extends-number-and-list-t-exten), and you must choose wisely which to use.

Comment: Even if getFoo simply returns Foo, the code is still going to be type safe. Why doesn't the compiler simply allow returning Foo if it sees that Foo is bound to a type parameter that extends something? Any implementation of Foo will have it's type parameter limited to a subclass of Bar or Bar itself at the least

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it required that I specify that getFoo returns a Foo< ? extends Bar>

As opposed to what? Returning a Foo which implicitly uses the generic Bar? That is not the same.

Let's use a concrete example:

```
List<? extends Number> getList();
```

This methods signature would tell you that it returns either a `List<Integer>` or a `List<Float>` or a List of any other subtype of Number. But the List will only contain objects of this one subtype. In this case the wildcard operator is used to signify to the caller that you just cannot tell him which subtype is used.

That is not the same as returning a List of Numbers, because a List of Numbers would be allowed to contain objects of any subtype of Number.

This distinction is important: If you returned a `List<Number>` the caller would be allowed to add any Number objects to the List. So the List would suddenly contain a mixture of Numbers whereas previously it only contained Integers. Using the wildcard operator prevents this, as the compiler cannot check whether the new Number is of the correct type.

And it is important that the compiler checks it. If it didn't you might run into `ClassCastExceptions` in other parts of your code, where the List is used with a concrete generic instead of the wildcard.

Comment: A `List` can be of any generic type, based on its type definition. In this case, a `Foo` can only be something that extends `Bar`, or `Bar` itself. It would be analogous to a `public interface NumberList<T extends Number>`.

Comment: You seem to think that returning the generic `<? extends Bar>` is  equivalent to returning the generic `<Bar>`. While this might work in your case, this is simply not true. I used the List example to explain the difference.