# Generics Java Wildcards and Subtyping

Tags: java, generics

I am reading on Generics in Java atm, and things go a little slow would love some help. I read from Oracles own database:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

At the bottom we can see `List<Integer>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`

I also came across this stackoverflow question:

[Java Generic type : difference between List <? extends Number> and List <T extends Number>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187005/java-generic-type-difference-between-list-extends-number-and-list-t-exten)

Which says in one answer: this is true:

```
((List<Integer>)list).add((int) s);
```

I have verified it, so that's ok. But I don't understand It completely.

What if the Wildcard is the Short class and I add a number higher than 2^15-1(=32767) Shouldn't it give error?

I even tried something like this and it works fine:

```
import java.util.*;
class CastingWildcard{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Short>();
        int s=32770;
        ((List<Integer>)list).add((int) s);
        System.out.println(list.get(0));
    }
}
```

To sum up: Why Can I cast `List<? extends Number>` to `List<Integer>` when the wildcard could be Short, and even Byte, which also extends Number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast makes the compiler ignore the fact, that the types may not be assignable.

At runtime the type parameters are unimportant, see [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

The `ArrayList` internally stores the content in a `Object[]` array, which means you can add any reference type to the list object, if you "abuse" casting.

You may get a exception when you retrieve a Object though, since there's a cast hidden in the `get` statement.

Example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
List<String> list2 = (List) list;
list2.add("Hello World");

Integer i = list.get(0); // works
String s = list2.get(3); // works
s = list2.get(1); // ClassCastException
i = list.get(3); // ClassCastException
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look at it later.

Comment: What does casting to (List) without a Type mean? Is it equal to `List<String> list2  = (List<String>)(Object)list` on your second line there? Refering from this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917844/how-to-cast-listobject-to-listmyclass

Answer (score 1):

You can cast an object to anything you want, but it might fail at runtime. However since generics information isn't present during runtime, your code becomes essentially `((List)list).add(s);`. At that point `list` will take **any** object, not just a `Number`. Generics can help you avoid casts and keep type safety during compile time, but during runtime they don't matter anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look at it later.