# What is the difference between <? extends Base> and <T extends Base>?

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, arraylist, jvm

In this example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Example {
    static void doesntCompile(Map<Integer, List<? extends Number>> map) {}
    static <T extends Number> void compiles(Map<Integer, List<T>> map) {}

    static void function(List<? extends Number> outer)
    {
        doesntCompile(new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>());
        compiles(new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>());
    }
}
```

`doesntCompile()` fails to compile with:

```
Example.java:9: error: incompatible types: HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>> cannot be converted to Map<Integer,List<? extends Number>>
        doesntCompile(new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>());
                      ^
```

while `compiles()` is accepted by the compiler.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18242094/8414561) explains that the only difference is that unlike `<? ...>`, `<T ...>` lets you reference the type later, which doesn't seem to be the case.

What is the difference between `<? extends Number>` and `<T extends Number>` in this case and why doesn't the first compile?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209170/discussion-on-question-by-dev-null-what-is-the-difference-between-extends-bas).

Comment: [1] [Java Generic type : difference between List <? extends Number> and List <T extends Number>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18187005/2985643) appears to be asking the same question, but while it may be of interest it is not really a duplicate. [2] While this is a good question, the title doesn't properly reflect the specific question being asked in the final sentence.

Comment: This is already answered here [Java Generic List<List<? extends Number>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746089/java-generic-listlist-extends-number)

Comment: How about the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By defining the method with the following signature:

```
static <T extends Number> void compiles(Map<Integer, List<T>> map) {}
```

and invoking it like:

```
compiles(new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>());
```

you're matching `T` against the type you're providing.

In the jls [§8.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) we find, that (interesting part bolded by me):

> A generic class declaration defines a set of parameterized types (§4.5), **one for each possible invocation of the type parameter section by type arguments**. All of these parameterized types share the same class at run time.

In other words, the type `T` is matched against the input type and assigned `Integer`. The signature will effectively become `static void compiles(Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map)`.

When it comes to `doesntCompile` method, jls defines rules of subtyping ([§4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1), bolded by me):

> A type argument T1 is said to contain another type argument T2, written T2 <= T1, if the set of types denoted by T2 is provably a subset of the set of types denoted by T1 under the reflexive and transitive closure of the following rules (where <: denotes subtyping (§4.10)):
>
> - ? extends T <= ? extends S if T <: S
> - ? extends T <= ?
> - ? super T <= ? super S if S <: T
> - ? super T <= ?
> - ? super T <= ? extends Object
> - T <= T
> - **T <= ? extends T**
> - T <= ? super T

This means, that `? extends Number` indeed contains `Integer` or even `List<? extends Number>` contains `List<Integer>`, but it's not the case for `Map<Integer, List<? extends Number>>` and `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`. More on that topic can be found [in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java). You can still make the version with `?` wildcard work by declaring, that you expect a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`:

```
public class Example {
    // now it compiles
    static void doesntCompile(Map<Integer, ? extends List<? extends Number>> map) {}
    static <T extends Number> void compiles(Map<Integer, List<T>> map) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doesntCompile(new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>());
        compiles(new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>());
    }
}
```

Comment: [1] I think you meant `? extends Number` rather than `? extends Numeric`. [2] Your assertion that _"it's not the case for List<? extends Number> and List<Integer>"_ is incorrect. As @VinceEmigh has already pointed out, you can create a method `static void demo(List<? extends Number> lst) { }` and call it like this `demo(new ArrayList<Integer>());` or this `demo(new ArrayList<Float>());`, and the code compiles and runs OK. Or am I perhaps misreading or misunderstanding what you stated?

Comment: @You're right in both cases. When it comes to your second point, I wrote it in a misleading way. I meant `List<? extends Number>` as a type parameter of the whole map, not itself. Thank you very much for the comment.

Comment: @skomisa from the same reason `List<Number>` does not contain `List<Integer>`. Suppose you have a function `static void check(List<Number> numbers) {}`. When invoking with `check(new ArrayList<Integer>());` it does not compile, you have to define the method as `static void check(List<? extends Number> numbers) {}`. With the map it's the same but with more nesting.

Comment: @skomisa just as `Number` is a type parameter of list and you need to add `? extends` to make it covariant, `List<? extends Number>` is a type parameter of `Map` and also needs `? extends` for covariance.

Comment: OK. Since you provided the solution for a multi level wildcard (aka _"nested wildcard"_?), and linked to the relevant JLS reference, have the bounty.

Answer (score 6):

In the call:

```
compiles(new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>());
```

T is matched to Integer, so the type of the argument is a `Map<Integer,List<Integer>>`. It's not the case for the method `doesntCompile`: the type of the argument stays `Map<Integer, List<? extends Number>>` whatever the actual argument in the call; and that is not assignable from `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>`.

UPDATE

In the `doesntCompile` method, nothing prevents you to do something like this:

```
static void doesntCompile(Map<Integer, List<? extends Number>> map) {
    map.put(1, new ArrayList<Double>());
}
```

So obviously, it cannot accept a `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` as the argument.

Comment: What would a valid call to `doesntCompile` be like, then? Just curious about that.

Comment: @XtremeBiker `doesntCompile(new HashMap<Integer, List<? extends Number>>());` would work, as would `doesntCompile(new HashMap<>());`.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, even this would work, Map<Integer, List<? extends Number>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<? extends Number>>();
     map.put(null, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        doesntCompile(map);

Comment: "that is not assignable from `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>`" could you please elaborate why it is not assignable from it?

Comment: What is the difference between this and `static void demo(List<? extends Number> list)`? You are not allowed to do `list.add(new Double(0.0))` inside it either, but it fails to compile inside `demo`, not outside like `doesntCompile`.

Comment: @DevNull In your `demo` example, `list` is a list of some unknown type extending `Number`, so you don't know that this unknown type is `Double`; hence the compilation error.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough: why in case 1 (in the update to this answer) a potential compilation error (`map.put(...)`) _inside of a method_ leads to a compilation error _outside_ of the method, while in case 2 (`demo`) it gets inside of the method and fails to compile _there_?

Comment: @MauricePerry sorry for the edit, I have mistakenly thought your answer was mine. Already reverted:)

Answer (score 2):

Simplied example of demonstration. Same example can be visualize like below.

```
static void demo(List<Pair<? extends Number>> lst) {} // doesn't work
static void demo(List<? extends Pair<? extends Number>> lst) {} // works
demo(new ArrayList<Pair<Integer>()); // works
demo(new ArrayList<SubPair<Integer>()); // works for subtype too

public static class Pair<T> {}
public static class SubPair<T> extends Pair<T> {}
```

`List<Pair<? extends Number>>` is a multi-level wildcards type whereas `List<? extends Number>` is a standard wildcard type .

Valid concrete instantiations of the wild card type `List<? extends Number>` include `Number` and any subtypes of `Number` whereas in case of `List<Pair<? extends Number>>` which is a type argument of type argument and itself has a concrete instantiation of the generic type.

Generics are invariant so `Pair<? extends Number>` wild card type can only accept `Pair<? extends Number>>`. Inner type `? extends Number` is already covariant. You have to make the enclosing type as covariant to allow covariance.

Comment: How is it that `<Pair<Integer>>` doesn't work with `<Pair<? extends Number>>` but does work with `<T extends Number> <Pair<T>>`?

Comment: @jaco0646 You are essentially asking the same question as the OP, and [the answer from Andronicus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60585268/2985643) has been accepted. See the code example in that answer.

Comment: @skomisa, yes, I'm asking the same question for a couple of reasons: one is that this answer doesn't actually seem to address the OP's question; but two is that I find this answer easier to comprehend. I cannot follow the answer from Andronicus in any way that leads me to understand nested vs non-nested generics, or even `T` vs `?`. Part of the problem is that when Andronicus reaches the vital point of his explanation, he defers to another thread that uses only trivial examples. I was hoping to get a clearer and more complete answer here.

Comment: @jaco0646 OK. The document _"Java Generics FAQs - Type Arguments"_ by Angelika Langer has an FAQ titled [What do multi-level (i.e., nested) wildcards mean?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ104). That is the best source I know of for explaining the issues raised in the OP's question. The rules for nested wildcards are neither straightforward nor intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to look in [documentation of generic wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) especially [guidelines for wildcard use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html)

Frankly speaking your method #doesntCompile

```
static void doesntCompile(Map<Integer, List<? extends Number>> map) {}
```

and call like

```
doesntCompile(new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>());
```

**Is fundamentally incorrect**

Let's add **legal** implementation:

```
    static void doesntCompile(Map<Integer, List<? extends Number>> map) {
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(0.);
        map.put(0, list);
    }
```

It is really fine, because Double extends Number, so put `List<Double>` is absolutely fine as well as `List<Integer>`, right?

However, do you still suppose it's **legal** to pass here *`new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>()`* from your example?

Compiler does not think so, and is doing his (its?) best to avoid such situations.

Try to do the same implementation with method #compile and compiler will obviously does not allow you to put a list of doubles into map.

```
    static <T extends Number> void compiles(Map<Integer, List<T>> map) {
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(10.);
        map.put(10, list); // does not compile
    }
```

Basically you can put nothing but `List<T>` that's why it's safe to call that method with *`new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>()`* or *`new HashMap<Integer, List<Double>>()`* or *`new HashMap<Integer, List<Long>>()`* or *`new HashMap<Integer, List<Number>>()`*.

**So in a nutshell, you are trying to cheat with compiler and it fairly defends against such cheating.**

NB: answer posted by [Maurice Perry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7036419/maurice-perry) is absolutely correct. I'm just not sure it's clear enough, so tried (really hope I managed to) to add more extensive post.